# Como posso fazer um relógio com horário brasileiro em tempo real

Tags: javascript

Pretendo fazer um relógio com horário brasileiro, que sempre que passa um segundo ele mostre que passou, ou seja.

São 14:10:12, 14:10:13 etc...

Como poderei fazer?

Obrigado

Comment: Coloquei a tag errada, é do habito kk

Comment: um simples relógio animado correndo os segundos?

Answer (score 10):

Uma maneira bem simples de fazer isso, usando [timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Sao_Paulo):

```js
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,1000);
    function myTimer() {
        var d = new Date(), displayDate;
       if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
          displayDate = d.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
       } else {
          displayDate = d.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', {timeZone: 'America/Belem'});
       }
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = displayDate;
    }
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: No Firefox está sendo lançado erros no console: `"message": "RangeError: invalid time zone in DateTimeFormat(): AMERICA/SAO_PAULO"`

Comment: O ideal é utilizar o timezone do lado servidor, pois o javascript não enviar esta informação de maneira segura.

Comment: A propriedade existe nos outros navegadores, o firefox lança essa mensagem porque não reconhece zonas por cidade. Ele concentrou tudo apenas num único local por país.

Answer (score 2):

Com jQuery, eu fiz uma vez assim:

```
var $clock = $('#real-clock');

setInterval(function () {

    $clock.html((new Date).toLocaleString().substr(11, 8));

}, 1000);
```

Dá pra fazer com javascript puro também:

```js
var clock = document.getElementById('real-clock');
    

setInterval(function () {
    clock.innerHTML = ((new Date).toLocaleString().substr(11, 8));  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="real-clock"></div>
```

Usei o `setInterval` com o segundo parâmetro `1000` para que a atualização ocorra de 1 em 1 segundo.

Comment: Isto assim, funciona pelo horario do meu computador, no caso eu sou de Portugal, vejo o horario português, e eu queria um relogio com horario brasileiro.

Comment: Não conheço muito de Javascript, mas tenta substituir por `new Date().toString().substr(16, 8)`.

Answer (score 1):

Pegar a Data pelo Javascript irá sempre retornar o horário atual do computador onde o Javascript roda (no cliente), então se o relógio do usuário estiver incorreto, o seu relógio também estará.

Creio que a maneira mais "segura" seja pegar esse horário do servidor que está executando a aplicação.

Para efeito de explicação vou deixar tudo junto, mas depois aconselho você a fazer um arquivo PHP e pegar as informações com um AJAX de vez em quando para se manter sincronizado,desta forma você pode utilizar um servidor [NTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592142/retrieve-time-from-ntp-server-via-php) para manter ele sempre sincronizado.

(É mais fácil você garantir o horário do servidor do que garantir o horário no cliente)

```
<html>
<input type="text" id="hora"/ >
<script>
(function() {
    var time=new Date(<?=gmmktime()?>000);  // 000 -> transforma os segundos retornados pelo PHP em milissegundos que são esperados pelo Javascript
    var hora = document.getElementById('hora');
    setInterval(function () {
        hora.value = ((new Date(<?=gmmktime()?>000)).toLocaleString().substr(11, 8)); 
    }, 1000);
    })();
</script>
</html>
```